# Jquery remove form tag, not content

Tags: jquery

Hello i need to remove a form tag but non the content:

```
<form id="form">
<div> not remove this only the form tag</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 26):

```
$form = $('#form');
$form.replaceWith($form.html());
```

Should do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

add an id or class to your div

e.g.

```
<form id="form">
<div class="wrapper"> not remove this only the form tag</div></form>
```

Then

```
$(".wrapper").unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the form tag from the DOM, all of its children elements go right with it. The only way you could achieve what you are asking is to pull all of the form tag's immediate children and append them to some other node in the DOM to keep them from disappearing from the page

Answer (score 0):

In case you have many elements that need to be modified:

```
$('.element').replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).html();
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/calvintennant/mdrHb/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.element').replaceWith(function() {
```

return $(this).html();
});

This is wrong....

```
$form = $('#form');
```

$form.replaceWith($form.html());

This one is correct...

Comment: Can you explain WHY one is correct and the other one isn't?

Answer (score -2):

if it's xml (as pages generated by dotNet), just remove the form node